# Как исправить ошибку #1064 в запросе

Tags: mysql

Нужно получить суффикс название таблицы с одной таблицы и выполнить запрос.

Запрос:

```
SELECT d.value 
FROM fur_attributes AS a 
LEFT JOIN fur_attr_network AS n ON  n.attr_id = a.id 
LEFT JOIN CONCAT("fur_attr_", a.typeData) As n2 ON n2.id_data = d.id
```

Ошибка:

> ```
> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax;
> check the manual that corresponds to your 
> MySQL server version for the right syntax to
> use near '("fur_attr_", a.typeData) as n2 ON n2.id_data = d.id
> LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1
> ```

Comment: что происходит когда выполняешь запрос? какие ошибки? что пишет? какова структура таблиц?

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, забыл написать, дополнил вопрос

Comment: это вы хотите выбрать данные из основной таблицы, а потом на их основании приклеить другую таблицу? я мб конечно не силен в mysql, но это из области магии

Comment: @teran, я думаю решение есть. Дело в том, что если оставить чисто a.typeData - запрос выполняется правильно ( т.е выбирает базу по содержанию a.typeData)

Comment: Джойнятся таблицы, а никак не функции.

Comment: @РоманЗахряпа пишет: *проверьте правильность запроса(поля, таблицы)*.

Answer (score 0):

Средствами MySQL невозможно сделать то, что Вы пытаетесь.

Разберем по порядку.

MySQL server Вам и пишет же, где синтаксис его смущает. Обращайте внимание сразу на начало - где начинается "косяк":

> LEFT JOIN **CONCAT("fur_attr_", a.typeData)**

Вы пытаетесь вместо названия таблицы подставить значение выражения - так не получится. По-человечески - понятно, что именно Вы хотите получить, но логика работы MySQL не позволит этого сделать. Синтаксическому анализатору нужно построить "план запроса" - а как Вы представляете это сделать? Если даже неизвестно - какие именно таблицы нужно брать (ведь это мы узнаем только после того, как возьмем первую таблицу, подклеим к ней вторую и выполним все вычисления).